# Why isn't there a document.createHTMLNode()?

Tags: javascript, dom, createtextnode

I want to insert html at the current range (a W3C Range).

I guess i have to use the method insertNode. And it works great with text.

Example:

```
var node = document.createTextNode("some text");
range.insertNode(node);
```

The problem is that i want to insert html (might be something like "<h1>test</h1>some more text"). And there is no createHTMLNode().

I've tried to use createElement('div'), give it an id, and the html as innerHTML and then trying to replace it with it's nodeValue after inserting it but it gives me DOM Errors.

Is there a way to do this without getting an extra html-element around the html i want to insert?

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.insertNode) you can insert DOM elements just fine. So please post code and error messages and we'll help you debug it..

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle demo (or the code itself)? I haven't worked with ranges much so I'm not sure I could recreate your situation....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `"<h1>test</h1>some more text"` consists of an HTML element and two pieces of text. It isn't **a** node.

If you want to insert HTML then use `innerHTML`.

> Is there a way to do this without getting an extra html-element around the html i want to insert?

Create an element (don't add it to the document). Set its innerHTML. Then move all its child nodes by looping over `foo.childNodes`.

Answer (score 6):

In some browsers (notably not any version of IE), `Range` objects have an originally non-standard [`createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.createContextualFragment) that may help. It's likely that future versions of browsers such as IE will implement this now that [it has been standardized](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#extensions-to-the-range-interface).

Here's an example:

```
var frag = range.createContextualFragment("<h1>test</h1>some more text");
range.insertNode(frag);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
function createHTMLNode(htmlCode, tooltip) {
    // create html node
    var htmlNode = document.createElement('span');
    htmlNode.innerHTML = htmlCode
    htmlNode.className = 'treehtml';
    htmlNode.setAttribute('title', tooltip);
    return htmlNode;
}
```

From:  http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid21CDC3EB9772B0A50EA149866133F0269A1D37FA.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of innerHTML just use appendChild(element); <del>[this](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp) may help you.
If you want comment here, and I will give you an example</del>.

Comment: Absolutely, and the best method for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The Range.insertNode() method inserts a node at the start of the Range.

```
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

var node = document.createElement('b');

node.innerHTML = 'bold text';

range.insertNode(node);
```

**Resources**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/insertNode